# Constrained Deep Learning

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, similarity

What are the ways to perform constrained optimization of weights in deep model? I am working on deep similarity learning, and many methods are based on constrained optimization; the vast majority of deep learning methods, however, only rely on unconstrained optimization. Are there any was to implement constraints in SGD?

Comment: Which framework are you using? Keras can handle custom constraints. Have a look at https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/constraints.py

Comment: @Learningisamess, I'm not quite sure about those custom constraints. It seems to me that after an iteration, it just artificially modifies weights so they satisfy the constraints. It's not evident to me that the result would have anything to do with constrained problem we originally wanted to solve. In addition, as far as I know, constraints in similarity learning are more complex than simple weight constraints, an are more like "objects that are labeled as far should not be closer that threshold". Now that I think of it more, there might be no better way than just incorporate it in loss.